# test ruby class method calls method in another gem

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubygems

So I have a ruby class that imports and uses a ruby gem. The gem is tested on its own but I want to write a test that makes sure my class method calls the correct method on the gem.

Im not sure how that will work.

Here is my class method:

```
  def article_body
    renderer = ArticleBodyRenderer.new
    renderer.to_html(data.fetch(:body))
  end
```

I want my test to check that this method calls: `renderer.to_html()`

How would I do this in ruby. I am using rspec unit tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure that the `renderer` initialize within the method is stubbed, you need to use an ["Any instance of" stub](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance). So:

```
let(:formatted_text) { '<foo>bar</foo>' }

it 'calls the to_html on rendered' do
  allow_any_instance_of(ArticleBodyRenderer).to receive(:to_html).and_return(formatted_text)
  expect(subject.article_body).to eq(formatted_text)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes the test pass!

Answer (score 2):

You should extract the `renderer` instance into its own method:

```
def renderer
  @renderer ||= ArticleBodyRenderer.new
end

def article_body
  renderer.to_html(data.fetch(:body))
end
```

This allows you to mock it more easily, for example with an [instance double](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-5/docs/verifying-doubles/using-an-instance-double):

```
renderer_double = instance_double('ArticleBodyRenderer')
allow(your_instance).to receive(:renderer).and_return(renderer_double)

expect(renderer_double).to receive(:to_hml).with(...)
your_instance.article_body
```

Or via a [spy](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-5/docs/basics/spies):

```
renderer_spy = spy('ArticleBodyRenderer')
allow(your_instance).to receive(:renderer).and_return(renderer_spy)

your_instance.article_body
expect(renderer_spy).to have_received(:to_hml).with(...)
```

Comment: That is fantastic thank you! The example using an instance_double is great

Answer (score 1):

Should be something along these lines:

```
let(:renderer) { ArticleBodyRenderer.new }

it 'calls the to_html on rendered' do
  expect(renderer).to receive(:to_html)
  subject.article_body
end
```

The logic is as follows: first you say that you expect some object to receive some message (method being called on this object), and than you trigger something, that should actually perform the expected method call on the expected object.

Comment: dam is it really that easy? Ill try this out now. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Can i ask for this line is for `subject.article_body`

Comment: @chinds so the logic is as follows: first you say that you expect some object to receive some message (method being called on this object), and than you trigger something, that should actually perform the expected method call on the expected object.

Comment: Ok, That makes sense.

So with your example that test is failing. It says it cant fine the key `body` on this line `subject.article_body` my guess is because it thinks that is an method on an object when it is in fact a part of a larger class named `Article`

Comment: @chinds not sure how it is implemented because I am not aware of details. Play with it having in mind the idea

Comment: The `renderer` instance in the `let` statement is not the same instance being created within the `article_body`. I think you need to use an "Any instance of" stub: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance

Comment: @ReggieB right-right, good point! Not sure that they still have expect_any_instance_of in RSpec 3. I think we could use `allow_any_instance_of(ArticleBodyRenderer).to receive(:new).and_return(renderer)` to make sure it's the same object